# BibTeX (TeX Live 2013) doesn't escape & in url

Tags: bibtex, line-breaking, urls

BibTeX (TeX Live 2013 on ubuntu) doesn't escape the `&` specifically in **urls**. The `%` escapes but not `&`.

For example I have the following reference:

```
@article{benson1975,
    title = {The Interorganizational Network as a Political Economy},
    volume = {20},
    issn = {00018392},
    url = {http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2391696?uid=3737664&uid=2134&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102581457607},
    doi = {10.2307/2391696},
    number = {2},
    urldate = {2013-08-25},
    journal = {Administrative Science Quarterly},
    author = {Benson, J. Kenneth},
    month = jun,
    year = {1975},
    pages = {229}
}
```

and when I cite it the `bbl` files keeps the `&` intact like this:

```
\htmladdnormallink{$<$http:\-/\-/www\-.jstor\-.org\-/discover\-/10\-.2307\-/2391696?uid=3737664&uid=2134&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102581457607$>$}{http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2391696?uid=3737664&uid=2134&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102581457607}.}
```

When I manual replace the `&` inside the `\htmladdnormallink` with `\&` LaTeX compiles perfectly so I'm sure that is there is a way to escape the & it would work like a charm.

Note that escaping the & on BibTeX (`\&`) doesn't work (works outside of urls, but not in urls). The `bbl` result is {`\textbackslash`} `&` instead of `\&`:

```
\htmladdnormallink{$<$http:\-/\-/www\-.jstor\-.org\-/discover\-/10\-.2307\-/2391696?uid=3737664{\textbackslash}&uid=2134{\textbackslash}&uid=2129{\textbackslash}&uid=2{\textbackslash}&uid=70{\textbackslash}&uid=4{\textbackslash}&sid=21102581457607$>$}{http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2391696?uid=3737664\&uid=2134\&uid=2129\&uid=2\&uid=70\&uid=4\&sid=21102581457607}.}
```

If it makes a difference, I'm using:

```
\documentclass[
    article,
    11pt,
    oneside,
    a4paper,
    english,
    brazil
    ]{abntex2}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={\@title}, 
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    pdfcreator={\@author},
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=blue,
    bookmarksdepth=4
}
```

Comment: I don't know `abntex2` class, but maybe the problem is somehow related to it? Try to use a more standard document class for the MWE - maybe this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

So after some fiddling around I found an option to in `abntex2cite` to change the url package from `hyperref` to `url`.

```
\usepackage[alf, abnt-url-package=url]{abntex2cite}
```

This fixes the problem with `&`, but creates the same problem with `%`. Fortunately it is possible to escape using `\%`. The same may happen with other special characters.

Anyways, when I checked the `.bbl` I noticed the `&` is not escaped there, even tough it compiles:

```
\url{http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2391696?uid=3737664&uid=2134&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102581457607}.}
```

Now I don't know if the bug is actually from `hyperref`, which should be able to escape `&` as the `url` package is or if it a `abntex2` bug. Whichever that is, I inspected `abntex2-alf.bst` in the `abntex2` package and was able to fix the problem by inserting the line below in the middle of `filter.url.tex` function:

```
duplicate$ "&" = {pop$ "\&" } 'skip$ if$
```

I will post this bug and fix on `abntex2` bugtracker.